# Adding right click option to a frame in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple explorer with tkinter python and I want to add a right click option to the files and folder buttons like copy, cut, delete, etc.
If somehow I can add a frame to wherever the user has right clicked then I can place all the buttons in that frame.
This is the [file.](https://github.com/Adityasingh76/Adityasingh76/blob/main/explorer.py)
Please help and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example Tkinter file that has the features you're talking about:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
  
root = Tk()
  
L = Label(root, text ="Right-click to display menu",
          width = 40, height = 20)
L.pack()
  
m = Menu(root, tearoff = 0)
m.add_command(label ="Cut")
m.add_command(label ="Copy")
m.add_command(label ="Paste")
m.add_command(label ="Reload")
m.add_separator()
m.add_command(label ="Rename")
  
def do_popup(event):
    try:
        m.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
    finally:
        m.grab_release()
  
L.bind("<Button-3>", do_popup)
  
mainloop()
```

Implement it as you need